# Converting Markdown to HTML5 slides via Pandoc through knitr in R

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

Since version 1.2 `knitr` has a new function `pandoc` to convert markdown document to other formats via pandoc directly in `R` ([See here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/)). For example

```
library(knitr)
pandoc('foo.md', format='html')  # HTML
```

I wonder how to convert Markdown document ([See knitr-slides.md for MWE](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/slides/)) to `HTML5` slides. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, add the following to your `.Rmd` document:

```
<!--pandoc
s:
S:
i:
mathjax:
-->
```

Then use the command

```
library(knitr)
knit("foo.Rmd")
pandoc("foo.md", format="dzslides")
```

This will still create the file `foo.html`, but will use the pandoc command

```
pandoc  -s -S --mathjax -f markdown -t dzslides -o foo.html 'foo.md'
```

to create it, which will result in the output being in HTML5 slides.

Comment: Thanks @David for your answer. But this does not work as expected. Output is in html format but these are not slides.

Comment: I suspect you need to add the option `-s` (or `--standalone`).

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane: Yep I had just remembered the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRobinson for your answer. If <!--pandoc s: S: i: mathjax: --> in the start of the .Rmd document, these words disturb the title.

Comment: @MYaseen208: Then don't put it at the start- put it at the end, or after the title.