# Is it possible to generate io-slides HTML5 presentations using pandoc?

Tags: html, pandoc

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is a nice command line which makes it easy to make html5 presentations such as reveal.js and so on. Does anyone know if it's possible to add other frameworks such as [io-slides](https://code.google.com/p/io-2012-slides/) ?

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487822/converting-markdown-to-html5-slides-via-pandoc-through-knitr-in-r

Comment: sure, create a new template with the relevant HTML/CSS: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates